React to Keyboard Height Change in React Native
We are using Keyboard Avoiding View in our React Native app, and we have run into the problem that, on android, if the user switches from a numerical to a normal TextInput or vis versa, the keyboard height changes and the view does not adjust to the new height. This leaves either a space above the keyboard or a hidden area below it.
We have tried listening to Keyboard events, but nothing is fired when the keyboard type is changed. I could manually add padding, but I have no way of knowing if the difference is standard across devices. Does anyone know of a way to fix this issue?
